# Fix the bug for waste management presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

please correct this VBA code for the ppt presentation

```
Sub CreateWasteManagementPresentation()
    Dim pptApp As Object
    Dim pptPresentation As Object
    Dim pptSlide As Object
    
    ' Create a new instance of PowerPoint
    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    
    ' Create a new presentation
    Set pptPresentation = pptApp.Presentations.Add
    
    ' Add Slide 1: Title Slide
    Set pptSlide = pptPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11)
    With pptSlide
        .Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Waste Management in Engineering Industries"
    End With
    
    ' Add Slide 2: Introduction
    Set pptSlide = pptPresentation.Slides.Add(2, 11)
    With pptSlide
        .Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Introduction"
        .Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Waste management is a crucial aspect of engineering industries. Effective waste management practices help minimize environmental impact and promote sustainability."
    End With
    
    ' Add Slide 3: Types of Waste
    Set pptSlide = pptPresentation.Slides.Add(3, 11)
    With pptSlide
        .Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Types of Waste"
        .Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Engineering industries generate various types of waste, including:"
        With .Shapes.AddTextbox(1, 100, 150, 600, 200).TextFrame.TextRange
            .Text = "1. Solid Waste: This includes materials like packaging, scrap metal, and construction debris." & vbCrLf & _
                    "2. Liquid Waste: Generated from processes like wastewater and chemical spills." & vbCrLf & _
                    "3. Hazardous Waste: Materials that are potentially harmful to human health and the environment." & vbCrLf & _
                    "4. E-waste: Discarded electronic devices, such as computers and mobile phones."
        End With
    End With
    
    ' Add Slide 4: Waste Management Strategies
    Set pptSlide = pptPresentation.Slides.Add(4, 11)
    With pptSlide
        .Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Waste Management Strategies"
        .Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Engineering industries employ various strategies to manage waste effectively, including:"
        With .Shapes.AddTextbox(1, 100, 150, 600, 200).TextFrame.TextRange
            .Text = "1. Source Reduction: Minimizing waste generation by optimizing processes and reducing material usage." & vbCrLf & _
                    "2. Recycling: Reusing materials or converting them into new products to minimize waste." & vbCrLf & _
                    "3. Treatment and Disposal: Properly treating hazardous waste and disposing of it in compliance with regulations." & vbCrLf & _
                    "4. Waste-to-Energy: Utilizing waste as a fuel source to generate energy."
        End With
    End With
    
    ' Save the presentation
    pptPresentation.SaveAs "C:\Path\To\Save\WasteManagementPresentation.pptx"
    
    ' Close PowerPoint
    pptPresentation.Close
    pptApp.Quit
    
    ' Release the objects from memory
    Set pptSlide = Nothing
    Set pptPresentation = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Waste Management presentation created successfully!"
End Sub
```

code says there is a bug in

```
.Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Waste management is a crucial aspect of engineering industries. Effective waste management practices help minimize environmental impact and promote sustainability."
```

i want a make a presentation

Comment: How many `pptSlide.Shapes.Placeholders` are in the collection?

Comment: >>  Set pptSlide = pptPresentation.Slides.Add(2, 11)   You've added a new Title Only slide to the presentation. The only placeholder on it is the Title placeholder, so there's no .Shapes.Placeholders(2)

Comment: "code says there is a bug" - that's not a very useful description of the *specific* problem you're seeing when you run your code.

Comment: as there seems to be no real automatisation, why are younhandling this with code?